# Extending custom library 1 with custom library 2 in codeigniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I have a custom library that we will call library1. I'm trying to extended library1 with another custom library called library2.

I could do a require_once and include library1 in library2. The other option would be to have library2 use codeigniters load method and load library1 from inside library2.

Any one have any thoughts on why one way is better than the other?

Comment: Without digging into the source code I am not 100% sure, but I would guess that the CI load method effectively just does a `require_once`, possibly performing a couple of extra `file_exists()` etc checks. I would go the CI load route, because of the fact it will probably provide an extra safety net, and even if it doesn't it won;t really cost anything.

Comment: Thanks this actually ended up being more complex as it was an abstract class which I did not notice at first so I was unable to use the native codeigniter load method to handle this. In the end I was able to just refactor the code into one library that makes it much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: No worries - please either answer your own question and accept it or delete this one, so it is closed off and people don't keep coming here seeing an unanswered question.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

First of all, "oop"? I think you are seriously missing the point of mcv, secondly check [this here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

> "CodeIgniter’s Hooks feature provides a means to tap into and modify the inner workings of the framework without hacking the core files. When CodeIgniter runs it follows a specific execution process, diagramed in the Application Flow page. There may be instances, however, where you’d like to cause some action to take place at a particular stage in the execution process. For example, you might want to run a script right before your controllers get loaded, or right after, or you might want to trigger one of your own scripts in some other location."

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto this problem recently, and for me using require_once proved to be a simple and efficient solution.